# In the context of fetch getReader how do I tell if the reader completed on its own or if it was cancelled?

Tags: fetch-api

This is my code:

```
async function streamData(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
  } else {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    let data;
  
    try {
      while (true) {
        data = await reader.read();

        if (data.done) {
          console.log('Stream has been cancelled or fully read.');
          break;
        } else {
          console.log(data.value);  // Handle your chunk data
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === 'AbortError') {
        console.log('Stream has been cancelled by client.');
      } else {
        console.log('An unexpected error occurred.', error);
      }
    } finally {
      reader.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}

streamData('http://your-url.com');
```

I cannot seem to find documentation about to distinguish between the reader getting cancelled and it completing to read.

`done` is true in both cases.

Is there a way to do that by inspecting the state of the reader or do I need to track myself when I cancel the reader?